# BAADF00D Access Violation

Tags: c++, access-violation

Sorry to ask for an answer to something so probably simple, but I can't figure this one out by myself, it seems.

So, I have a header file, like so:

```
#ifndef LEVELMAP_H
#define LEVELMAP_H

#include "Constants.h"

class LevelMap
{
public:
LevelMap(int map[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH]);
~LevelMap();
int GetTileAt(unsigned int h, unsigned int w);

private:
int** mMap;
};
#endif LEVELMAP_H
```

And a .ccp file like so:

```
#include "LevelMap.h"

// 0 = empty, 1 = blocked

LevelMap::LevelMap(int map[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH])
{
    //Allocate memory for the level map.
    mMap = new int*[MAP_HEIGHT];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        mMap[i] = new int[MAP_WIDTH];
    }

    //Populate the array.
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < MAP_WIDTH; j++)
        {
            mMap[i][j] = map[i][j];
        }
    }
}

LevelMap::~LevelMap()
{
    //Delete all elements of the array.
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        delete [] mMap[i];
    }
    delete [] mMap;
}

int LevelMap::GetTileAt(unsigned int h, unsigned int w)
{
    if(h < MAP_HEIGHT && w < MAP_WIDTH)
    {
        return mMap[h][w];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I get an access violation on the 'return mMap[h][w];' line, and I can't for the life of me figure out a solution.

For context, GetTileAt() is being used to detect if a certain tile on the screen should allow the player to collide with it or not.

Comment: Looks good. Can you show us the usage?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're constructing your `LevelMap` object with that constructor? (It's easy to accidentally use the default constructor with no parameters, unless you explicitly prevent that in your class declaration.)

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield - defining a custom constructor prevents the automatic generation of default constructors. In this case, there's no default constructor and copy constructor.

Comment: Since the two macros exist, is there a specific reason to not use them for the internal mMap declaration?

Comment: If the map size is constant, use a C array, not a dynamic one. If it is not constant, use vector<vector<int>>.

Comment: Along the line of what Neil was saying. If you want dynamic allocation of the array, but the sizes are fixed (understandable if you have a fixed array *of these* in automatic scope and want to minimize the stack-hit), use `std::vector<std::array<int, MAP_WIDTH>>` and construct it in an initialization list via `mMap(MAX_HEIGHT)`

Comment: Oh, and regarding your access violation, make sure you're compliant with the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). If your map objects are being copied or assigned **anywhere** and you didn't properly override the copy-ctor and assignment operator, you're double-freeing the underlying buffer allocations, as the default versions of those implementations are just copying the base pointer and your copy will be using the same pointer(s) as the source. As soon as one destructs, the other is invalid. Both Neil's approach and mine will solve that for you.

Comment: What are you trying to eat exactly?

Comment: What are the values of h and w when you get the crash?  Is it the very first time you use GetTileAt or does it work a few times and then suddenly crash at a certain point?

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving the exact error message that you get, but from the title I deduce that this is what you are looking at:

> 0xBAADF00D : Used by Microsoft's debug HeapAlloc() to mark uninitialized allocated heap memory

Which in your case would mean that `mMap` was never created. Try to delete all default constructors to find the exact error causing this. The default move, copy, and empty constructors will not work properly anyways, so it is good practice to delete them!